# Disk shows blk_update_request after restarting

Tags: ssh, disk-usage, disk

I'm using Ubuntu Server 22.04. The disk shows blk_update_request and spams it into console after I shut it down remotely and it worked perfectly fine before, but now it shows this error. I suppose it can be disk, that is broken, because I booted it back up a few seconds later after turning it off. It also started moving its head once in a second instead of being silent (probably because it pings for a sector which has an error)

Strangely I don't have a chance to work with it via keyboard since it is blocked with this message. I can still connect to it via ssh, but my nextcloud server is not working anymore. I can work with it via ssh freely, so can I backup all of my data or should I somehow restore the sector without losing all the data?

I also noticed that other system messages appear in my console after startup

[Full video and photos on errors here](https://dropmefiles.com/oFeOY)

[image]

Comment: UNC is an uncorrectable error. I'd check what SMART data says, eg via `sudo smartctl` (usually also accessible from your partition manager). You might want to also check for drive overheating.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "blk\_update\_request: I/O error" mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883215/what-does-blk-update-request-i-o-error-mean)

Answer (score 1):

This error is unccorectable.Only right thing is to backup your data ASAP and try to get warranty on this disk

Such errors can occur due to poor disk storage before it is sold.